# common.exception.ApiException: QuickAction NewCase is not accessible

Tags: community, quickaction

**Given**

- Existing Community with Guest User Access only
- OOTB [Community component](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_contact_support_button.htm&type=5) `Contact Support Button`
- Guest User configured to have access to Support API and Global NewCase action; Read/Create privileges on `Case`.

**When**

- Contact Support Button clicked

**Then**

- To the guest user, case is accepted with response as configured in the `Contact Support Button` component
- Sysadmin gets email from Salesforce that looks like this:

  ```
   Salesforce could not create this case because of the reason listed below. We will try creating the case again. For more information about this error or help with Web-to-Case, please contact Customer Support.

   Reason: common.exception.ApiException: QuickAction NewCase is not accessible

   Record Information:

  _quickActionName = NewCase
  _record = {"Description":"ff","Reason_for_Contact__c":"Inquiry","First_Name__c":"fred",
             "Subject":"from community","Last_Name__c":"fubar","Email__c":"foo@bar.com"}
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*self-answering as this took me a while to figure out so hopefully this helps the next person*

Because this was an existing Community and the Contact Support button had worked previously, consider what changed.  In this example, recordtypes were added to `Case` where none had existed previously.

So, what you need to do:

- Grant Guest user access to the recordtypes in the Guest User Profile with an appropriate default.
- Since the Community was using the OOTB `Contact Support Button` component, this is tied to the default Global Action `New Case`.  Edit the `New Case` Global Action and associate it with a recordtype available to the Guest user.

Why? because [Default Global Actions](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=actions_and_record_types.htm&type=5) associated with `-master-` recordtype won't be available to Guest Users once you enable recordTypes for that object and hence the error message ensues.

*Note: You could also use a custom New Case global action that you made available to the site's Guest User provided it was associated to a recordtype available to the Guest User.*

[image]